# What site should my question about a stellar system game go on?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am building a little game in Unity. This game has the player flying around in a stellar system operating under gravity. Unfortunately, the n-body simulation code I'm using is not working correctly (Planet's orbits are forming rosettes rather than ellipses).

What site should I ask for help on? Game Development? Physics? Space Exploration? Code Review? Stack Overflow?

The problem is with my physics simulation, for sure. But the problem could be in Unity specific code and not in the physics code.

Comment: Oh wait! Physics.SE is for physics physics, not game physics! :P Definitely not physics.SE and not space exploration.SE.

Comment: The thing is I AM doing physics physics. If I had said that I was writing n-body simulation code in an effort to prove a theory for a paper I'm working on, would that change anything? I'd still be using Unity for physics physics.

Comment: Ah, I don't recall any question on physics.SE about physics physics related to game physics. What I can suggest now is going to one of the per site metas and asking if it's on topic.

Comment: FWIW I'm a mod on Physics. @Shane If you go to our meta you'll probably get the same advice as in my answer (but you're welcome to do so, if you want perspectives from other community members).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: I think this isn't a duplicate because in my involves the point where problems in code meet problem, in non-code and whether my question should go on a programming site, or, a non-programming site. IOW, if I were writing a program to determine the world's best travel location, should I ask on SO, or, travel.SE? A question of the differences between the various programming related SE sites does not answer that IMO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest Game Development first, and if it turns out not to be well received there, try Stack Overflow second. Your question sounds like a code question which puts it off topic on Physics and Space Exploration. And Code Review is for code samples that basically work, but where you want to know how to improve their style or efficiency.

Comment: The thing is though, it might be a code question, but, it could very well be a math question. If physics simulations are off topic for physics.se entirely though, that's fine.

Comment: It's not quite that physics simulations are off topic, it's that you have to be asking about the physics, not the code. A good rule of thumb is that, if you're having a problem that would occur even if you weren't doing a computer simulation, it might be on topic for [physics.SE]. If your problem only arises in code, it's off topic. Incidentally, I think we've had pretty much that exact question before ("why aren't my orbits elliptical?") and it's always been off topic in the past. I doubt that your case is different. But you can ask a more detailed question on [meta.physics.SE] if you want.

Comment: Do you happen to know if the questions were migrated and answered? I'd be great if I didn't create any dupes on game dev. I couldn't find anything when I searched.

Comment: Not offhand. I can't seem to find them either.